# CommonJS loader for browsers?

Tags: commonjs

to increase the velocity of my development, i'd like to use commonjs for my client-side and server-side javascript, so i can use a common codebase/libraries across all of my projects.
Why not AMD? browsers and node support AMD, but phantomjs does not, and i can switch to that later for optimal (browser) production builds.

Looking around, I can't find ANY module loaders that directly support CommonJS. You always have to write wrappers/etc over them, or require bootstrapping configs.

Do I have any options other?

Comment: i found browserify http://browserify.org/  but that bundles everything together into an 'emulated' node application.  so not what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

**no commonjs loaders......**

so i ended up using AMD for both browser and nodejs.

because I code everything using Typescript, for phantomjs I have a seperate build process that takes all my source and builds a mirror of it in commonjs format.

as i mention in my comment, you could kind of use CommonJs in the browser with http://browserify.org/  but that bundles everything into it's own runtime, not what i want.